# Can we using Linq Union to combine two sessions in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I've two sessions in my controller, `sessCash` and `sessFuel`.

Which both of them stored the values from two different tables, `tblCash` and `tblFuel`, with similar fields.

`tblCash`

```
---------------------------
Id  |  Type      |  Price |
----+------------+--------+
c1  | Electronic | 200    |
c2  | Water      | 50     |
---------------------------
```

`tblFuel`

```
--------------------
Id  | Type | Price |
----+------+-------+
f1  | Fuel | 5     |
f2  | Fuel | 10    |
--------------------
```

The `tblFuel` is separate from `tblCash` for future queries.

I want to combine into one view in my index.cshtml but without using union in sql query but rather using linq union on my project.

How can I do that?

I've tried this

```
sessCash.OrderBy(x => x.Type).Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Type, x.Price}).Union(sessFuel(...//I'm not sure how to continue
```

Thanks.

Comment: Select the same parameters as the first (Cash) projection `.Union(sessFuel.Select(f => new { Id = f.Id, Type = f.Type, Price = f.Price }))`.

Comment: But you will probably want to project into a view model, rather than using anonymous objects if you using the data in a view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, every time I'm using codes like @Jasen said, it's got an error `cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list anonymous type#1 '`

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there any better solution for this?

Comment: No, They are different types so you cannot use a straight `.Union()` or `.Concat()` Just create a view model with those 3 properties and use `.Select(x => new YourViewModel { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `tblCash` and `tblFuel` are different types (even though they contain identical property names), you will need to create a view model and project you queries into a collection of that view model

```
public class MyVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } // or enum?
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and then the query becomes

```
var model = sessCash.OrderBy(x => x.Type).Select(x => new MyVM
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Type = x.Type,
    Price = x.Price
}).Union(sessFuel.OrderBy(x => x.Type).Select(x => new MyVM
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Type = x.Type,
    Price = x.Price  
});
return view(model);
```

and in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<MyVM>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Muecke answer, if you have image data type probably it will couse some error. You can join by making the second variabel to store sessFuel.

```
var modela = sessCash.OrderBy(x => x.Type).Select(x => new MyVM
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Type = x.Type,
    Price = x.Price,
    Image = x.Image
}).toList();
var modelb = sessFuel.OrderBy(x => x.Type).Select(x => new MyVM
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Type = x.Type,
    Price = x.Price,
    Image = x.Image  
}).toList();
var model = modela.Union(modelb).toList();
return view(model);
```